# Method Illuminate\Routing\PendingResourceRegistration::withTrashed does not exist

Tags: laravel

I have route like this

```
    Route::apiResource('article.comment', ArticleCommentController::class)->except('destroy', 'update');
    Route::apiResource('article.comment', ArticleCommentController::class)->only('update')->withTrashed();
```

But, when I am check the routing using `php artisan r:l`, show error like this

```
  BadMethodCallException 

  Method Illuminate\Routing\PendingResourceRegistration::withTrashed does not exist.

  at D:\dev\api_app\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Macroable\Traits\Macroable.php:113
    109▕      */
    110▕     public function __call($method, $parameters)
    111▕     {
    112▕         if (! static::hasMacro($method)) {
  ➜ 113▕             throw new BadMethodCallException(sprintf(
    114▕                 'Method %s::%s does not exist.', static::class, $method
    115▕             ));
    116▕         }
    117▕

  • Bad Method Call: Did you mean Illuminate\Routing\PendingResourceRegistration::withoutMiddleware() ?

  1   D:\dev\api_app\routes\api.php:88
      Illuminate\Routing\PendingResourceRegistration::__call("withTrashed", [])

  2   D:\dev\api_app\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php:423
      Illuminate\Routing\RouteFileRegistrar::{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Routing\Router))
```

why, method `->withTrashed()` can't add to route resource?

Comment: What's your Laravel version?

Comment: Perhaps you should have answered the question above. This method has only been available since [Laravel 9.35](https://github.com/laravel/framework/releases/tag/v9.35.0).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you use `withTrashed()` method in route?
you should use `withTrashed()` in Eloquent Queries ( in your controller)

Change your routes to :

```
    Route::apiResource('article.comment', ArticleCommentController::class)->only('update');
```

And in your controller get items with `withTrashed()` method.

For example ( in your Controller ) :

```
$articleComment = ArticleComment::withTrashed()->find($your_update_id);
// Then do what you want ...
```

Comment: My Eloquent model is already using 'Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes' but still error.

Comment: I mean if the `->withTrashed()` method can be applied to the route resource it will shorten the code rather than checking the trashed model on the controller or route service provider

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. According to the docs this should be possible - https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/controllers#soft-deleted-models
The benefit of doing this on the route is that with Route Model Binding you don't then need to call the model in the controller.

Answer (score 1):

If you want your `apiResource` to return models that have been deleted using `softDeletes`, you can override the `resolveRouteBinding` method on the model.

```
class YourModel extends Model {

  use SoftDeletes;

  public function resolveRouteBinding($value, $field = null) {
    return $this->withTrashed()->where($field ?? $this->getRouteKeyName(), $value)->firstOrFail();
  }
```

This will allow you to use the route model binding from the `apiResource` route, rather than having to call the model explicitly in the controller.